# MongoDB update command retain first and last element of an array field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java-driver

I have a scenario where I'd like to be able to remove all elements except the first and the last (by position in the array) from an array field in all documents in a mongo collection matching a certain query. I've tried the following command which only retains the first element:

```
db.collection.update(*query*,
{
  $push : {
     arrayField : {
       $each : [],
       $slice : 1,
       $slice : -1
     }
  }
},
{
  multi : true
})
```

Unfortunately I don't think what I want to achieve is possible using a simple update.

Ultimately I am going to be orchestrating this this with a java client application using the mongo java driver and I don't want to have to retrieve all the documents, modify them appropriately and then persist the changes.

Any ideas for a solution which will run on the server?

Comment: You would be better off explaining your actual problem you need to solve here. Clearly storing results in an array and trying to keep the "first" and "last" entries only on an update is not the way to go. At any rate, you would just end up with an array of two entries. It's likely your real problem could be solved with an application of the [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/min/) and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/max/) update operators, if you took the time to explain that problem instead.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I think I've explained the problem? I want to remove all elements of an array field except the first and last by position. If you want context, I want to perform this action as part of a housekeeping activity at a point in time at which, for certain documents, the elements between the first and last are no longer of use. The values of the contents of the elements are unknown at the point at which I want to do this therefore $min and $max are of no use. An alternative is to read the documents into my application, modify the array and then re-persist which is not what I want to do.

Comment: You've already been told that first and last from array will not work so the idea here is to forget looking towards that as a solution and instead explain how you even arrived and thinking that you would use an array in the first place. So usually when you are told "You cannot do that", and people ask "what were you really trying to get out of this?", then you can either choose to accept the help and advice or just keep banging your head against a wall. I see no content here that exposes your problem to be solved other than what "you think" the solution is, and you've been told no to that.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I appreciate that there is more than one way to skin a cat, and if what I want to do can't be done (which is what you're telling me) then so be it, I will take another approach.